# impossible Poisson's ratio of Lennard-Jones potential type solid (cubic cristal for example), or any potential depending on $r$

Tags: thermodynamics, potential, elasticity, stress-strain

We know (for instance : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson%27s_ratio ) that the Poisson ratio is 
$\nu=1/2-Y/(6B)$, with $Y$ the Young modulus and $B$ the bulk modulus.

Let's assume we have a energy density $f(r)$ that depends on the distance $r$ between 2 particles of the solid. It can thus also be written as depending on the volume fraction of the solid $\phi$, or on the volumic mass $\rho$ for a homogeneous solid, with a relation : $\phi=\phi(r)$, $\rho=\rho(r)$...

The potential we're talking about has a minimum at $r_0$ (or $\phi_0$, $\rho_0$), where $f'(r)=0$.

The energy for a volume $v$ will be $F(v,r)=v f(r)$. For a cubic cristal, $v=r_0^3$.

If we assume free stress boundary condition, the osmotic pressure is zero, and $f=\rho df/d\rho=0$.

**The Young modulus**

If we deform a small volume $r_0^3$ Young modulus will write,  (see http://www.animations.physics.unsw.edu.au/jw/elasticity.htm for instance) : $Y=r_0^2\frac{d^2f}{dr^2}\Big|_{r=r_0}$.

**The Bulk modulus**

Similarly, one can compute the bulk modulus for a simple cubic cristal (see for instance https://eis.hu.edu.jo/ACUploads/10010/Cohesive%20energy-2.pdf page 7) : $B=\frac{r_0^2}{9}\frac{d^2f}{dr^2}\Big|_{r=r_0}$

**The Poisson's ratio**

It comes out $\nu=-1$ !!!! What's the error ???

Comment: Why do you think there is an error?

Comment: Well $\nu=-1$ is the lowest possible value for Poisson's ratio with some weird mechanical properties ! It sounds strange that a "cubic cristal" share those properties. Moreover, this result doesn't depend on a specific potential, so it's true also for a Lennard-Jones potential in a cristal atom, or for a colloidal aggregate with a cubic structure. I'm taking always the cubic structure since it's the easiest, but the result is not really different for any other common structure...

Comment: Well, it is still a possible value. Now, you should google "poisson ratio lennard jones solid" and look through some of the papers and see how others have gotten to an expression for Poisson's ratio.

Comment: That's what I did, but I didn't find any theoretical derivation, even now it's a quite simple calculus. As I wrote, some people compute the Young modulus and others the Bulk modulus, or make assumptions and afterwards calculations. Some papers also make more a numerical computations. Anyway my result is not consistent...

Comment: If you consider that hand-wavy estimates of stiffness based on the potential energy curvature and the geometry of a toy model are good only for (say) order-of-magnitude predictions, then the question becomes moot. I would say you've (re)discovered that these models don't handle lateral atomic motion very accurately.

Comment: U're maybe right but I see in the litterature that people take it seriously for the Young and Bulk modulus. But indeed maybe the cumulative error is too large